# How do I change font in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

In winforms it was easy

```
private void mfont_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    fd.ShowColor = true;
    fd.ShowDialog();
    txt.Font = fd.Font;
    txt.ForeColor = fd.Color;
}
```

How do I do the same in WPF? I opened font dialog, but I don't know how to make these two lines work in WPF:

```
private void mfont_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    txt.Font = fd.Font;
    txt.ForeColor = fd.Color;
}
```

Comment: have a look on properties of the object IE Click on the element to set font of, and in properties you can set it up. If you want to do it in code, set id of the element, and after you set it in code

Answer (score 1):

You can use `txt.FontFamily`, `FontWeight`, `FontStyle` etc...

WPF is all about Binding, therefore a lot of things are different than WinForms. Mostly because of Bindings some things like Font are split up in multiple properties like p.e. FontFamily, FontWeight and FontStyle, this makes things easier for Binding.

Take a look at:
Your answer: [TextBox in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.aspx) and [FontFamily Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.fontfamily.aspx)
[Bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) (Strongly adviced to read in advance)
[An introduction to WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970268.aspx) (Perhaps this can help you.)

WPF may look like WinForms, but it is definitely different. However in my opinion the benefits of WPF outweigh the benefits of WinForms greatly. Good luck.